# Nunit execute test methods in parallel but not tests

Tags: c#, nunit

I have a class with three methods each with their own "TestCaseSource". The goal is to have the three methods run in parallel, but the tests within each method to run concurrently.

I have tried changing the parallelizable setting on both the class and method levels, but the only way I seem to be able to get any parallel execution is with "ParallelScope.All", which just runs them all in parallel.

```
[TestCaseSource("T1")]
[Parallelizable]

public void T1Tests(string a, int b)
{
//Call methods, do stuff
}

[TestCaseSource("T2")]
[Parallelizable]

public void T2Tests(string a, int b)
{
//Call methods, do stuff
}

[TestCaseSource("T3")]
[Parallelizable]

public void T3Tests(string a, int b)
{
//Call methods, do stuff
}

public static IEnumerable<TestCaseSource> T1()
{
return BaseT("");
}

public static IEnumerable<TestCaseSource> T2()
{
return BaseT("");
}

public static IEnumerable<TestCaseSource> T3()
{
return BaseT("");
}

public static IEnumerable<TestCaseSource> BaseT(string d)
{
.....
}
```

Comment: As in you want (T1Tests,T2Tests,T3Tests) to run on three threads - each thread running the test cases in serial?

Comment: Wai Ha Lee, that is exactly what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Although NUnit creates a test suite for the method, which then holds the individual test cases, there is no way to apply the `Parallelizable` attribute specifically to that method. It's just something that has not come up before.

`Parallelizable` only applies to test cases and test fixtures, so the only way to make this work would be to place the three methods in three separate (maybe nested?) fixtures.